# How to integrate push notification in Angular 7 using signalR and API in C#?

Tags: c#, typescript, signalr, angular7

I have a Angular 7 application in which I want to implement push notification using SignlaR (2.4.4 version) with API in C#. Can anyone suggest how to solve my problem?

I have tried everything that I can, but I am not able to establish a connection between Angular SignalR client and SignalR Hub created in C# API.

1) This is my Startup.cs

```cs
HubConfiguration cfg = new HubConfiguration();
app.MapSignalR<PersistentConnection>("/ClientHub");
app.MapSignalR(cfg);
```

2) This is my Hub

```cs
public class ClientHub : Hub
{
    public Task SendNotificationCount(int chatUserCnt)
    {
        var context = 
        GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ClientHub>();
        return context.Clients.All.SendAsync("Send", chatUserCnt);
    }

    public Task SendHelloToAll(string message)
    {
        var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ClientHub>();
        return context.Clients.All.SendMsgAsync("SendToAll", message);
    }
}
```

3) This is Angular Code where I am trying to Connect to the Hub.

```cs
hubUrl = http://localhost:60067/ClientHub
connectToHub(hubUrl:string) {
    this.connection = new HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl(hubUrl).build();
    this.connection.start().then(() => {
        console.log("connected to hub");
        this.connection.on('SendToAll', (message) => { 
            alert(message);
        });
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

I am expecting, whenever there is a change in the database for notification to get alerts through the Hub in realtime. Also I want to send database changes using signalR hub to Angular. But I am not able to connect with hub from Angular.

Comment: You can take a look at my repo on GitHub. Server side is dotnet core 2.2 and frontend is angular: https://github.com/Thorstensen/chtr

Answer (score 0):

This is where I would start looking:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr-typescript-webpack?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio